# Structures inside Structures C/C++

Tags: c, header, struct, contains

I just recently switched over from Java programming to C/C++ programming so forgive me if this is a silly question:

I have a header file which is composed of a structure which includes 2 structures from another header file in a different location. It looks something like this:

```
struct A {
   struct B variable1;
   struct C *variable2;
   ... more variable declarations here.
};
```

The header files which contains the declarations for struct B and struct C are not included in this specific header file, but even if I do include them it makes no difference - in both scenarios at compilation time I get

```
error: field 'variable1' has incomplete type
```

I am just wondering if anyone knows what this could be from?
Thank you!

Comment: Please show the code for the definition of `struct B`...

Comment: Make sure that there aren't any macros wrapped around the declaration of `struct B` or `struct C` thats making them invisible in `struct A`.

Comment: Are you sure you declared struct B and struct C before struct A?

Answer (score 4):

If you don't include the definition of `struct B` you should get the mentioned error, since the size of the structure is then unknown. The type of `struct C` to which you only have  a pointer could just be pre-declared:

```
struct C;
```

If you do include the file with the definition of `struct B`, you should not get the error, so if you still do that points at some other error in your code.

Answer (score 1):

Could it be the order the structs are defined?  Struct B need be defined and ready before Struct A.

My test was:
works

```
struct b {
  int y;
};

struct a {
  int x;
  struct b c;
};
```

same error as you:

```
struct a {
  int x;
  struct b c;
};

struct b {
  int y;
};
```

Answer (score 1):

To declare an instance of `struct B`, the definition of `struct B` must be *complete*.  You state that

> The header files which contains the declarations for struct B and struct C are not included in this specific header file

At this point the compiler doesn't know what `struct B` looks like, so the type is *incomplete*; thus, it will reject any declaration that tries to create an *instance* of `struct B`, such as the declaration for `variable1`.  You *can* declare a pointer to an incomplete type, as you do with `variable2`, since struct pointer types all have the same size and representation.

Then you state

> but even if I do include them it makes no difference

which strongly suggests (to me, anyway) a circular dependency between `struct A` and `struct B`, which is bad juju.  `struct A` cannot be complete until `struct B` is complete, and `struct B` cannot be complete until `struct A` is complete.  Changing `variable1` to be a pointer to `struct B` should be enough to break that dependency.

If that is the case, you may want to revisit your design.

Answer (score 0):

**struct A** is defined here, and it must have a known size. The compiler has to know what is the size of **struct B** to calculate the size of **struct A**, so if **struct B** is not yet defined, you will not be able to use it in **struct A**.

You don't have that problem with **struct C***, since struct A only keeps a pointer to **struct C**, and the size of a pointer is known to the compiler. But you need to use forward declaration for it if it is not defined before **struct A**:

```
struct B {
   int b;
}
struct C;
struct A {
   struct B variable1;  // valid
   struct C *variable2; // valid
   struct D variable3;  // invalid
   struct D* variable4; // invalid
};

struct C {
    int c;
}

struct D {
    int d;
}
```

Answer (score -3):

Try forward declaration :

```
struct B;
struct C;  
struct A {
   struct B variable1;
   struct C *variable2;
   ... more variable declarations here.
};
```

Comment: -1: Forward declaration is not sufficient for `struct B` here.